# Java: set screen pixel color directly?

Tags: java, drawing, screen, pixel

I have searched for an answer for this question, but all attempts have proven no useful info.

I am trying to figure out a way to draw a pixel **directly** to the screen, without using a fullscreen canvas of sorts.

Is there any way to do this? If so, what is the best (And/Or most efficient) way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** For those who are confused, I am trying to draw *directly* to the screen, without a fullscreen canvas. I want to set a pixel color on the screen if you will, sort of like drawing to the video hardware.

Comment: You can create an undecorated frame with transparent background and render on that.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by avoiding a full-screen canvas? Is it so you won't capture clicks? Or do you need it to show the other applications where you haven't drawn anything?

Comment: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/jogl-applet-runner-newt-gears-special-napplet.html is rather interesting. (**Warning**: This JavaApplet takes some time to load. While loading it, the browser might not react.)